# disjoin browser from http - QtWebKit the right decision?

Tags: browser, webkit

im planning to create control-panels (touchscreeen-visualizations) for my house (KNX - bus). The control panel will be designed by HTML/CSS so it can also be accessed by a browser via the WWW. But inside the house i need a very fast and dynamic interface (eg use a js-slider and dimm a light in real-time). so i want to disjoin a browser from HTTP and control the DOM directly.

for example:

- a state in the house changes (eg light turns on). this event will *not* be notified to a webserver that waits for all the panels to pull for state-changes but will be directly broadcasted to all the panels where the DOM is updated by a controller-code.
- i click a button in the panel or move a slider. these events are not posted to a webserver, but are sent directly to the target KNX-actors. (light turns on / is dimmed)

so now im asking myself - how is this done?
i found the QtWebKit Module which seems to do just what i want:

"A bridge between the JavaScript execution environment and the Qt object model makes it possible for custom QObjects to be scripted. Integration with the Qt networking module enables Web pages to be transparently loaded from Web servers, the local file system or even the Qt resource system." (from the detailed desc.)

what do you think, is this the right way?

how fast is the webkit javascript engine? i need a very fast javascript engine, cause many of the controls that will be used by the panel will depend on javascript and have to be very reactive.

any pointers greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about webkit, but QtWebKit seems to render/execute quite (very?) slow, at least on my mac mini. Try out the [Arora](http://code.google.com/p/arora/) web browser and see what results you get.